# see the output in Airflow

Tags: python, pipeline, airflow

I am new to `Airflow`. I wrote a simple code to save a list in a `txt` file as below:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import datetime

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='example_dag',
  start_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
  schedule_interval='@once'
)

def push_function(**kwargs):
    ls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return ls

push_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_task',
    python_callable=push_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ls = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_task')
    with open('test.txt','w') as out:
        out.write(ls)
    out.close()

pull_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_task',
    python_callable=pull_function,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

push_task >> pull_task
```

when I use web server interface I see my dag. Also, I see my dag when I wrote `airflow list_dags` in `CLI`.

I also compiled my code using `python code.py`, and the result was like below without any error:

```
[2017-12-16 14:21:30,609] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2017-12-16 14:21:30,709] {driver.py:123} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2017-12-16 14:21:30,741] {driver.py:123} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
```

I both tried to run the dag with UI and with command `airflow trigger_dag Mydag`

However, I cannot see my txt result file after running. there is no error in log file either.

How can I find my txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I would try again with an absolute file path or you can try logging the current working directory inside the method with `os.getcwd()` to help locate your file.